# How to Hide *DTMF* number while making Phone Call in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to initiate a call which also contains DTMF Numbers
ex:- 012345678,1*0001*000*1*1#
and i'm using the following code to initiate the call

```
 guard let number = URL(string: "tel://" + number) else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.open(number)
```

and then the systems shows popup to the user to make the call with the Full number also including the DTMF.

so i was wondering if it is possible that we can hide the DTMF part from that Popup ?
so the user only sees "012345678" instead of "012345678,1*0001*000*1*1#" as this DTMF numbers are secure data that he shouldn't see it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible, as far as I know. That popup is created by iOS itself and you have no control over it.